# ¿Como eliminar registros en una lista por un valor definido en Java?

Tags: java, lista, map, collection

Hola a todos el problema es el siguiente, tengo una lista de datos:

La lista contiene estos datos:

```
Juan,Mexico,2
Pedro,Italia,1
Maria,Mexico,1
Liam,USA,2
Carlos,Canada,2
```

Requiero Eliminar los registros que contengan el numero 2 para que obtenga esta salida:

```
Pedro,Italia,1
Maria,Mexico,1
```

Y después de obtener la salida eliminar el dato que esta en la segunda posición y obtener la siguiente lista:

```
Pedro,Italia
Maria,Mexico
```

Alguna idea, ejemplo o documentación en la que pueda basarme para poder resolver  esto?

Para eliminar los datos que contengan ya sea 1 o 2 en la posición [2] lo realice metiendo los datos a un fichero ya que tengo mas experiencia en manejando ficheros. Esto es lo que he realizado hasta ahora:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        //Archivo donde coloque los registros de la lista
        File tempFile = new File("C:\\Users\\alex\\Desktop\\datos.csv");
        //Archivo donde guardo este resultado
        //Pedro,Italia,1
        //Maria,Mexico,1
        File tempFile2 = new File("C:\\Users\\alex\\Desktop\\datos2.csv");

           
    
        BufferedWriter writeduplicados = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
        BufferedWriter write = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile2));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tempFile));
        for (String lineas : lista) {
                
            writeduplicados.write(lineas + "\n");
        }
            
             writeduplicados.close();
        int lineToRemove = 1;
        
        
           String currentLine;
           while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               String[] line_arr = currentLine.split(",");
               
               
               int num_linea = Integer.parseInt(line_arr[2]);
               if(!(num_linea == lineToRemove)){
                    continue;
                 
               }else{
                   write.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));   
               }
         
           }
        
           write.close();
            reader.close();
        
           write.close();
            reader.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask].

Comment: Eso es muy fácil hacerlo con `streams`, incluso con un simple ciclo `for`, pero ¿Qué has intentado tú? Debes colocar tus intentos aunque no lo hayas podido lograr. Lee [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y edita tu pregunta colocando el código de lo que has intentado hasta ahora.

Comment: Para eliminar los datos que contengan ya sea 1 o 2 en la posición [2] lo realice metiendo los datos a un fichero ya que tengo mas experiencia en manejando ficheros aquí lo que he realizado https://onlinegdb.com/5SC4hvI5B , es la primera vez que realizo una pregunta, una disculpa si omití colocar lo que he realizado

Comment: Cuando te refieres a eliminar la línea si contiene 1, si la línea fuera `Pedro,Italia,11`, ¿La eliminarías igual o la dejarías?

Comment: Me refiero a que ese dato siempre será 1 o 2 , [Pedro,Italia,1] , [Maria,Mexico,1]

Comment: En lo que realice metiendo los datos en el fichero borra el registro si la posicion [2] es igual a 1

Comment: @Alexis_098 checa esto y verifica si es lo que buscas https://onlinegdb.com/ESWTLC1qoE

Comment: y cuando se requiere elimnar los que tengan el 2 en la posicion[2], solo cambio  int lineToRemove = 2;

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entendí queres leer un archivo y generar otro.
El nuevo generado tiene que eliminar las lineas que contienen el "2" en la ultima posición.

Podes hacerlo así (recorres 2 veces el archivo):

```
package prueba;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // Archivo en la carpeta del proyecto
        File tempFile = new File("datos.csv");
        //Archivo donde guardo este resultado
        //Pedro,Italia,1
        //Maria,Mexico,1
        File tempFile2 = new File("datos2.csv");
        
        BufferedWriter write;
        BufferedReader reader;
        List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        try {
            write = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile2));
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tempFile));
            String cadena;
            while((cadena = reader.readLine())!=null) { 
                lista.add(cadena);
            } 
            
            String lineToRemove = "2";
            for (String string : lista) {
                String data[] = string.split(",");
                if(!data[2].equalsIgnoreCase(lineToRemove))
                    write.write(data[0] + "," + data[1] + "\n");
            }
            write.close();
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("No se encuentra el archivo");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
}
```

O más eficiente porque recorres solo una vez y mas eficiente:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // Archivo en la carpeta del proyecto
        File tempFile = new File("datos.csv");
        //Archivo donde guardo este resultado
        //Pedro,Italia,1
        //Maria,Mexico,1
        File tempFile2 = new File("datos2.csv");
        
        BufferedWriter write;
        BufferedReader reader;
        
        try {
            write = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile2));
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tempFile));
            String cadena;
            String lineToRemove = "2";
            while((cadena = reader.readLine())!=null) { 
                String data[] = cadena.split(",");
                if(!data[2].equalsIgnoreCase(lineToRemove))
                    write.write(data[0] + "," + data[1] + "\n");
            } 
            
            write.close();
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("No se encuentra el archivo");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
}
```